# automatic redirect to login page after session timeOut in joomla 1.5.26

Tags: joomla-1.5, jsession

Due to audit of our client website the testing team told us that after login to admin pannel of website, if any user is idle for more than 5 min then it should redirect to login page.

I set the Session Lifetime to 5min in backend.
But problem is this that its logout only when page refresh.
Its should logout directly.
I am tired too many thing but nothing work..
Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm very surprised the audit didn't flag the use of Joomla 1.5.

Comment: Yes.. They told us to upgrade the joomla version. But upgrading from 1.5 to latest 3.8 is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Add the following before the closing head tag inside index.Php

```
    <script type=text/javascript>
setTimeout(' document.location=document.location' ,10000);
</script>
```

Comment: Its showing error:404 - An error has occurred.

Component Not Found

Comment: but i just modified your code with this:   <script type=text/javascript>
setTimeout(function(){ 
alert("Your session has been expired. Please login again.");
window.location.assign("http://eserverindia.in/dmdesic/administrator"); }, 70000);
</script>But this code will activate even if user is not loged in.